# Why I'm getting StackOverflowError

Tags: java, stack-overflow

```
public class Category {

    private Category parentCategory;
    private Set<Category> childCategories;
    private String name;

    public Category() {
        childCategories = new HashSet<Category>();
    }

    public Category getParentCategory() {
        return parentCategory;
    }

    public void setParentCategory(Category parentCategory) {
        this.parentCategory = parentCategory;
    }

    public Set<Category> getChildCategories() {
        return childCategories;
    }

    public void setChildCategories(Set<Category> childCategories) {
        this.childCategories = childCategories;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Category [childCategories=" + childCategories + ", name="
                + name + ", parentCategory=" + parentCategory + "]";
    }

}


public static void main(String[] args) {
        Category books = new Category();
        books.setName("Books");
        books.setParentCategory(null);

        Category novels = new Category();
        novels.setName("Novels");
        novels.setParentCategory(books);

        books.getChildCategories().add(novels);
        //novels.setChildCategories(null);

        System.out.println("Books > " + books);
    }
```

The `System.out.println` is generating the `StackOverflowError`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When you do your `toString()`, you call the `toString()` of the children. No problem here except that you call the `toString()` of the parent in here. Which will call the `toString()` of the children, etc.

Nice infinite loop.

The best way to get rid of it is to change your `toString()` method into :

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Category [childCategories=" + childCategories + ", name="
            + name + ", parentCategory=" + parentCategory.getName() + "]";
}
```

This way you don't print the parentCategory but only its name, no infinite loop, no StackOverflowError.

**EDIT:** As Bolo said below you will need to check that parentCategory is not null, you might have a `NullPointerException` if it is.

---

**Resources :**

- [Javadoc - StackOverflowError](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StackOverflowError.html)

**On the same topic :**

- [toString() in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161228/tostring-in-java)
- [StackOverFlowError in Java postfix calculator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420323/stackoverflowerror-in-java-postfix-calculator)

Comment: You'll get `NullPointerException` instead when `parentCategory == null`.

Comment: Just `parentCategory.getName()` will not be complete.

Answer (score 3):

Since the error is the `System.out.println` the problem must be in the `toString()`.

The problem is that `toString()` prints both parent and child `Category` object for the one your printing using their `toString()` method.  So when you print a Category it calls `toString()` on the parent which calls `toString()` on the child which calls `toString()` on the parent which calls `toString()` on the child and so on until the stack is exhausted.

Answer (score 2):

Because each call to `Category#toString()` produces a ton of other `toString`s. Notice that printing `childCategories` causes each element to be printed out (via `toString`), which in turn repeats this entire process of many `toString` method calls.

Not only that, but each child calls `toString` on its parent, which in turn calls `toString` on its children, which each calling `toString` on the parent, which in turn calls `toString` on its children, which...

Answer (score 2):

```
return "Category [childCategories=" + childCategories + ", name="
                + name + ", parentCategory=" + parentCategory + "]";
```

you are using instances like `parentCategory` to concat to your toString. it will call toString method of these instances.

this loop of toString calls never end. because  child Category will call Parent Category and Parent will call Childs again and so...

not that if you put: `System.out.println(myObject);`  it actually is: `System.out.println(myObject.toString());`

Answer (score 2):

Your `toString()` is going into recursive tailspin. You need to have two `toString()`; one for the parent and one for the children. Your `toString` can look like this :

```
@Override
public String toString() {
     toStringParent(parent);   // This print only parent
     toStringChildren(children);  // This print only children
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`StackOverflowError` is actually raised while building the `String` argument that would be passed to `System.out.println`.

Each time you concatenate a `String` and a `Category`, the `toString()` method of `Category` is executed.  The problem is that your `toString()` in `Category` is a bit too verbose.  One way to fix it is to print only the name of the parent category (skipping it's parent and children):

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Category [childCategories=" + childCategories + ", name="
            + name + ", parentCategory="
            + ((parentCategory == null) ? null : parentCategory.getName())
            + "]";
    }
```