# toString() function for JPA one-to-many relations raises StackOverflowError

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jackson

I have two JPA Entity classes, Task and TaskList. There's a one-to-many relationship between TaskList and Task (obviously) with the `tasklist_id` foreign key in the `task` table.

The `Task` class is this:

```
@Entity(name = "task")
public class Task implements Serializable {    

    // Id and 3 fields

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="tasklist_id")
    private TaskList parentList;

    // 3 more fields

    // Constructor
    public Task() {}

    //Getters and Setters
}
```

and the `TaskList` class is this:

```
@Entity(name = "task_list")
public class TaskList implements Serializable {

    // Id and two fields

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parentList")
    private List<Task> tasks;

    // Constructor
    public TaskList() {}
}
```

When I try to add an automatic getter and setter to these two classes and a toString() function, I get a StackOverflowError.

How do I go about writing getters and setters for the two fields so that I get a proper object with `toString()`?

Comment: Pretty like it is not a JPA/Hibernate. Read this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593893/why-im-getting-stackoverflowerror), maybe it can be relevant to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**To future readers, the solution is to use back references:**

Task class:

```
@Entity(name = "task")
public class Task implements Serializable {    

    // Id and 3 fields

    @JsonBackReference("task_list-task")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="tasklist_id")
    private TaskList parentList;

    // 3 more fields

    // Constructor
    public Task() {}

    //Getters and Setters
}
```

TaskList class

```
@Entity(name = "task_list")
public class TaskList implements Serializable {

    // Id and two fields

    @JsonManagedReference("task_list-task")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parentList")
    private List<Task> tasks;

    // Constructor
    public TaskList() {}
}
```

- Add the proper annotations. Add ManagedReference to @OneToMany(parent) and BackReference to @ManyToOne(child). Write table names in the brackets as indicated, separated by a hyphen.

This takes care of the infinite recursion automatically, solving the StackOverflowError problem.

Some links:

http://keenformatics.blogspot.in/2013/08/how-to-solve-json-infinite-recursion.html
http://vard-lokkur.blogspot.in/2010/10/json-jackson-to-rescue.html

Comment: Your answer isn't corresponding your question. Your question was about `toString()` implementation, not about conversion objects net to JSON. :)

Comment: This solution solves the fundamental problem - infinite recursion - that results from using toString() directly. Jackson is used there, as shown in the error log, so these annotations are relevant. Also, I've tested this in my own code personally. :)

Comment: There are not an error log, jackson or json tags in your question. :)

Comment: @v.ladynev Also, I have tried other ways, and none worked the way this did. Not to mention they were making writing some of other functions extremely difficult.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `tasks.toString()` the default implementation of `toString()` in the `AbstractCollection` call `toString()` for the every element in the list (for every `Task`). So you should not to use a default implementation and get information from the `tasks` in a loop and don't call `toString()` for every `Task` of course. You can get from the `Task` and add to a result string  task's id or name.